# how to match first regex occurrence using grok filter

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

my logs are in the following format `my.package.name classname: my_message`

I would like to cut the class perfix .

for example:

`com.example.Handler doPost:  request  received, jim:jay foo: bar`

convert to:

`request  received, jim:jay foo: bar`

I tied this

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {"message" => "^(.*):%{GREEDYDATA:request}"}
  }
}

output { stdout { codec => rubydebug  }}
```

but this is what I get:

```
{
       "request" => " bar",
       "message" => "com.example.Handler doPost:  request  received, jim:jay foo: bar"
       ...
}
```

seems like grok matches by last regex occurrence.

how can I match by **first** `:` occurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a reluctant `.*` by using `.*?`. A normal `.*` will match as much as it can while a reluctant `.*?` will match as little as it can.

Fun fact: The logstash grok DATA patterns are

```
DATA .*?
GREEDYDATA .*
```

So you can define your pattern as

```
^%{DATA}:%{GREEDYDATA:request}
```